n-Qubit depolarizing errors/pauli channels in stim circuits and approximate disjoint errors in the respective detector error model
Because it is not (yet?) available natively, I am currently implementing a $n$-qubit depolarizing error in stim using
def n_qubit_depolarizing_error(qubits : list[int], p : float) -> stim.Circuit:
    '''
    Model a n-qubit depolarizing error using correlated errors
    '''
    circuit = stim.Circuit()
    pauli_strings = [' '.join([f'{x}{qubits[i]}' for i,x in enumerate(q) if x !='I']) for q in it.product(['I','X','Y','Z'], repeat=len(qubits))][1:]
    n_error_mechanism = len(pauli_strings)
    
    p0 = p/n_error_mechanism
    circuit.append_from_stim_program_text(f"CORRELATED_ERROR({p0}) {pauli_strings[0]}")
    for i in range(1,n_error_mechanism):
            pi = p0/(1-i*p0)
            circuit.append_from_stim_program_text(f"ELSE_CORRELATED_ERROR({pi}) {pauli_strings[i]}")
    return circuit

i.e. using correlated errors with probabilites $p_k = \frac{p_0}{1-kp_0} = \frac{p}{4^n -1-kp}$.
When then generating a detector error model, I have to set the approximate_disjoint_errors=True flag in order to not raise an exception.
My question is whether this effectively again becomes a $n$-qubit depolarizing error model in the detector error model. I have not found how the details of how approximate_disjoint_errors=True acts.
For depolarizing errors and complicated circuits, I also don't get how the effective probabilities are calculated, but for a simple case of just correlated error simulating applying three qubit bit-flips with probability $p$ (here 60%):

shows that (at least in this case) my conjecture is true: the generated detector error model (circuit.detector_error_model(approximate_disjoint_errors=True)) has terms
error(0.2) D0 D1 D2
error(0.2) D1 D2
error(0.2) D2

and letting my errors get explained using circuit.explain_detector_error_model_errors( reduce_to_one_representative_error=True) shows
ExplainedError {
dem_error_terms: D0 D1 D2
    CircuitErrorLocation {
       flipped_pauli_product: X0*X1*X2
       Circuit location stack trace:
           (after 0 TICKs)
           at instruction #3 (ELSE_CORRELATED_ERROR) in the circuit
           at targets #1 to #3 of the instruction
           resolving to ELSE_CORRELATED_ERROR(0.333333) X0 X1 X2
     }
}

ExplainedError {
dem_error_terms: D1 D2
    CircuitErrorLocation {
        flipped_pauli_product: X0*X1
        Circuit location stack trace:
            (after 0 TICKs)
            at instruction #2 (ELSE_CORRELATED_ERROR) in the circuit
            at targets #1 to #2 of the instruction
            resolving to ELSE_CORRELATED_ERROR(0.25) X0 X1
     }
 }

ExplainedError {
    dem_error_terms: D2
    CircuitErrorLocation {
        flipped_pauli_product: X0
        Circuit location stack trace:
            (after 0 TICKs)
            at instruction #1 (E) in the circuit
            at target #1 of the instruction
            resolving to E(0.2) X0
     }
}

This question equally applies to the case where we have n-qubit pauli channels where the $p_k$ are defined differently.

You can simplify what you're doing in several ways.
First, you can use stim.PauliString.iter_all to more easily and quickly make the Pauli strings you want. It supports options like min/max weight so it gives you the freedom to truncate if you find the number of error terms is getting out of control.
Second, you aren't really benefiting from ELSE_CORRELATED_ERROR. You can just use a CORRELATED_ERROR separately for each pauli string, and convert from disjoint probabilities into independent probabilities by tweaking the probability argument as in https://algassert.com/post/2001 . This conversion is exact; so it bypasses all that approximation stuff. I believe the conversion formula is
$$p = \frac{1}2{} - \frac{1}{2} \left(1 - d\frac{4^n}{4^{n} - 1}\right)^{4^{1-n}}$$
where $n$ is the number of qubits and $d$ is the disjoint probability and $p$ is the independent probability. But you should double check that. For small values of $d$ this is $p = d \pm O(d^2) \approx d$.

My question is whether this effectively again becomes a n-qubit depolarizing error model in the detector error model.

When converting into a dem, stim approximates ELSE_CORRELATED_ERROR(p) terms by turning it into CORRELATED_ERROR(p*reached) where reached is the chance of the preceding CORRELATED_ERROR and ELSE_CORRELATED_ERROR terms not firing. But this is ultimately equivalent to approximating $p \approx d$. If you want the exact correct number, this is not quite that.
If you don't care about the conversion being exact, I recommend using CORRELATED_ERROR(d) with $d=q/(4^n-1)$ for each term (where $q$ is the noise strength).
If you want the conversion to be exact, use CORRELATED_ERROR(p) with $d \rightarrow p$ converted as above.
